# Help with positive- and negative-forms in Proof Theory

Tags: reference-request, logic, proof-theory

I need help in understanding a device used bu Kurt Schütte, *Proof Theory* (1977).

In treating *classical* sentential calculus, he use - in place of truth-tables - the device of *positive-* and *negative-forms* [page 10-on], called "a sort of generalization of the notions of 2succedents and antecedents formulas' of Gentzen's sequence calculus".

The idea is that $A$ is a positive (negative) part of $F$ if it occurs in $F$ in such a way that the truth of $A$ (falsity of $A$) implies the truth of $F$.

The simplest example is given by $F = (A_1 \land ... \land A_n \rightarrow B_1 \lor ... \lor B_m)$ where each $A_i$ is a negative part of $F$ and each $B_j$ a positive part; similarly for $F = (\lnot A_1 \lor ... \lor \lnot A_n \lor B_1 \lor ... \lor B_m)$. The
syntactic definition of these notions is given in terms of $P$-forms $\mathcal P[*]$ and
$N$-forms $\mathcal N[*]$ so that $A$ is a positive part of $F$ if $F = \mathcal P[A]$ for a $P$-form $\mathcal P$ (similarly for negative parts and $N$-forms). It is also necessary for setting up the logical systems to consider $NP$-forms $\mathcal Q[*_1,*_2]$ which are $\mathcal N$-forms in $*_1$ and $\mathcal P$-forms in $*_2$.

> Are there available some source explaining the "machinery" and supplying details about how they are used in Schütte's book for to proof the soundeness and completeness of *classical* propositional logic ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some remarks about positively (negatively) occurring subformulas in Sam Buss' *An Introduction to Proof Theory*, an article from the *Handbook of Proof Theory*. The article is available online:

http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~sbuss/ResearchWeb/handbookI/ChapterI.pdf

and the remarks start in section 1.2.10. However, this section is rather a prelude to some syntactic results and so may not be what you are looking for.

Comment: I'll look at it : Thanks !

Comment: I 've just noticed that Takeuti's standard monograph contains an appendix about Schütte's proof theory, which might be of interest to you.

Comment: I browsed it, but it seems to me that is about more specialized topics. In Takeuti there is a ref [page 280] to positive and negative aprts: it looks like Buss...

Comment: I've found Solomon Feferman's review of the engl transl of Schütte in *BULLETIN OF THE AMERICAN MATHEMATICAL SOCIETY* (1979) : "The subject matter of Part A is by now fairly standard, but the formal framework in terms of *positive* and *negative parts* is not [...]. I do not find it natural to work in Schütte's system despite its elegance. But as evidence that this is not just a personal prejudice it can be mentioned that the system has not caught on at all in the literature [...] And, it seems, there are good reasons to prefer Gentzen's sequential (or natural deduction) systems."

Comment: had a look a bit like Smullyans proof tableaux  see Smullyan's "first order logic" just (Seperatly) signed formula's, (but F A is equivalent to T ~P)  I am not so sure if it is of any real new use to be honnest.